# Using AndroidX Paging for non UI paging (e.g. in Services)

Tags: android, android-service, android-paging

The Paging docs start off with:

> The Paging Library helps you load and display small chunks of data at a time. Loading partial data on demand reduces usage of network bandwidth and system resources. [source](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/)

It's still unclear to me if Paging would be useful for **non-UI applications**. It looks like I can still use DataSources/ PagingSource and PagedLists, as a lazy loading list would be useful when processing data.

**My use case,** I want to load thousands of images to perform some processing in a *Foreground Service*. I will only inform the user once all images are processed through a notification, so no views are directly involved. I am confused. Perhaps the concept of Paging is not right because I am not showing a certain number of items to the user (a page). But then, I still need a **buffer** to load files efficiently and not bottleneck on IO. My initial implementation did IO and processing sequentially, and I can see a "jagged tooth" profile for the CPU usage.

**My question:** I would appreciate if someone could explain the actual flexibility of the Paging library for non-UI applications, and most importantly, let me know how to efficiently load files/ IO if the paging library is not the right fit.

Comment: "My initial implementation did IO and processing sequentially, and I can see a "jagged tooth" profile for the CPU usage" -- isn't that a matter of having appropriate thread pools for the I/O-bound and CPU-bound bits of work? "I would appreciate if someone could explain the actual flexibility of the Paging library for non-UI applications" -- unless you have to make a series of Web service calls to get the list of image URLs a page at a time, I suspect that Paging is not relevant for your scenario.

Comment: Thanks for your insight. Looks like you've helped me expose my shaky understanding of balancing multithreading. I was hoping `Paging` abstracts it away, but I will go deeper .